# Any software I can use on ubuntu to mirror one of my drives to other drives on my system in order to backup my files?

Tags: hard-drive, samba, backup, raid

I'm looking for something to use on ubuntu desktop 22.04 LTS that I can use to mirror one of my drives on my system to the other 3 drives on my system to backup my data. I am new to this.

```
Hardware info:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64
Host: MS-7D20 1.0
Kernel: 5.15.0-40-generic
Uptime: 27 days, 15 hours, 8 mins
Packages: 2148 (dpkg), 11 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.1.16
CPU: Intel i7-10700k
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 2060 SUPER x3
Memory: 29638 / 32GB
Drives:
512G Boot M.2
4x Seagate 3TB Drives

System used for mining/web server/minecraft server/NAS
```

Comment: What do you mean by "drives"? Physical whole disk? A partition? A filesystem? Or merely a filesystem? If you need simple file replication `rsync` is the tool to use.

Comment: @FedKad physical whole disk. thanks, I'll try rsync.

Comment: For mirroring you may want to setup RAID. But that is not backup, as any errors (on your part, such as deleting an important file) are instantly replicated to other drives. It is only useful for disk failures.

Comment: @user68186 how would I setup RAID if im running ubuntu desktop ?

Comment: @user68186 (software raid)

Comment: You may want to update your question. I have not set up RAID in my Ubuntu systems, but I am sure there are tutorials in the net.

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` is the tool to use if you want to create timestamped and incremental backups of your system. It basically allows you to restore your main system to a specific time (ie. "restore the system to what it was 2 days ago at 17:10" if that was a moment rsync was started).

If you need a desktop tool for rsync: [grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/), [luckybackup](http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/), [unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/). The last one is my favourite.

Sidenote: this is not mirroring. It is to make a backup not to create an identical second machine to act as a fallback.

Comment: Don't forget the default "Backup" app that comes with Ubuntu, the `deja-dup`. Even though the default setting back up only the current user's "Home" folder, it can be set to back up any data folder in the 3TB HDDs. I won't call "unison"  a backup solution for the same reason RAID1 is not a backup solution. It syncs folders (in multiple drives, in multiple computers) and if you delete something it is deleted in the other locations.